# Pinax npm installation failure

Tags: django, npm, npm-install, pinax

Can someone please look into the below error stack? I was trying to set up pinax.

```
(venv) C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite>npm install
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.79.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface
 has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.81.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, up
grade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated hawk@3.1.3: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported
 and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated uws@9.14.0: New code is available at github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets.js
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgra
de to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support
is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated boom@2.10.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgra
de to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support
is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@2.0.5: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please u
pgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid supp
ort is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated sntp@1.0.9: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported
 and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

> uws@9.14.0 install C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\uws
> node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0


> node-sass@4.7.2 install C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win32-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win32-x64-72_binding.node":

connect ETIMEDOUT 140.82.112.3:443

Timed out whilst downloading the prebuilt binary

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild -
-verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\ZinonYT\\PycharmProjects\\ReadyMade\\mysite\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.18.2 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\venv\Scripts\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\venv\Scripts\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % s
ys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ZinonYT\\PycharmProjects\\ReadyMade\\mysite\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\
\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ZinonYT\PycharmProjects\ReadyMade\mysite\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":
"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.12.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.1 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ZinonYT\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-11T09_19_41_066Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the npm sass used by the project is node-sass@4.7.2 but the node i installed was 10 in order to use node-sass@4.7.2 node 8 must be installed not 10 . so uninstall node 10 and install node 8.

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about doing an update of dependencies in a current release. Perhaps that will be fixed.